ValueError: If no `decoder_input_ids` or `decoder_inputs_embeds` are passed, `input_ids` cannot be `None`
I am trying to get the decoder hidden state of the florence 2 model. I was following this https://huggingface.co/microsoft/Florence-2-large/blob/main/modeling_florence2.py to understand the parameters that goes into the forward method.I tried something like
# Pass inputs to the model with output_hidden_states=True to get hidden states
with torch.no_grad():
outputs = model(
    input_ids=inputs["input_ids"],
    pixel_values=inputs["pixel_values"],
    attention_mask=inputs["attention_mask"],
    output_hidden_states=True,  # Request hidden states
)

But doing this I'm getting this error:
ValueError: If no decoder_input_ids or decoder_inputs_embeds are passed, input_ids cannot be None. Please pass either input_ids or decoder_input_ids or decoder_inputs_embeds.
I couldn't understand the error fully as it says "input_ids cannot be None" but my input_ids is not a None. It is something like:
tensor([[   0, 2264,  473,    5, 2274, 6192,  116,    2]], device='cuda:1')
Also I amm using this model for inference only, what does the decoder_input_ids mean and where I can find this to pass in the forward method.

please show what model you are currently using. and try rename your input_ids variable to decoder_input_ids or decoder_inputs_embeds.

I am using Florence-2-large from microsoft

Did you tried renaming your variables?
